# NoneType object has no attribute 'get_info'

Tags: usb, 64-bit, wubi, dvd, windows-vista

Still same problem! Trying to install ubuntu 14.04 into Vista (amd64), landing at NoneType object has no attribute 'get_info'. DL iso three times, md5 ok, and tried once as metalink (force-wubi).

When trying to install from DVD (F9-->DVD), will start reading DVD --> then black screen for 20s --> then Windows starts.
Same result from USB.

Any suggestions?